# Metaprogramming within docstring with @eval

Tags: julia

I'm attempting to associate a docstring with a function that is defined with an `@eval` macro; I also wish to use symbols to dynamically generate the docstrings.

```
for (f, name) in ((:add, :addition), ... )
    @eval begin
        @doc "Documentation for $name" ->
        function f(args)
             ## FUNCTION BODY
        end
    end
end
```

While I can successfully reference `$name` from within the `@eval` statement, I cannot reference `$name` from within the docstring itself. It gives the error `UndefVarError: name not defined`.

1) Is there a way to get this to work? I've tried a number of ways to get out of the `@doc` scope and to gain access to variables in the surrounding scope, but I haven't been successful.

2) What is the nature of the `->` syntax?
I got the `->` syntax from Github, but I can find no mention of it in the Julia documentation, and even having  used Julia for a decent while, I haven't encountered it before.

Comment: This might help https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!searchin/julia-users/docstrings/julia-users/fuEQCbLULSk/e67MVJcWBAAJ

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As linked to by @jverzani, all that is needed is an additional `$`. One `$` is needed for expression interpolation, and the other is needed for the string interpolation. The final code is as follows:

```
for (f, name) in ((:add, "addition"), (:sub, "subtraction"), ...)
    @eval begin
        @doc """
        This is the function $($name)
        """
        function $f()
            ## FUNCTION BODY
        end
    end
end
```

Super simple once you know the answer...

Comment: With Julia 0.5 `for (f, name) in ((:add, "addition"), (:sub, "subtraction"))
    @eval begin
        @doc """
        This is the function $($name)
        """
        function $f()
            ## FUNCTION BODY
        end
    end
end` raises `ERROR: LoadError: Invalid @var syntax 'This is the function '.` Removing @doc fix this... but docstring `?add` doesn't appear. Any idea?

Answer (score 4):

As @scls noted this needs to be slightly modified for Julia 0.5. From the [Advanced Usage](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.5/manual/documentation/#advanced-usage) section of the docs the above example should now look something like

```
for (f,n) in ((:foo, "foo"), (:bar, "bar"))
    @eval begin
                @doc "This is the function $($n)" $f
        function $f()
            println($n)
        end
    end
end
```

```